# Jenkins not triggering build on PR merged in bitbucket

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-webhook

We are using Bitbucket cloud to host our repos and Jenkins for CI/CD.

I have setup a multibranch pipeline which has develop and release branches. I want to trigger develop branch whenever a PR is merged from the feature branches to develop a branch (In fact on any manual webhook edit).

Below are the cases I tried:

1. *Setup **Manage hook** in Jenkin*:

- This creates a webhook in bitbucket and when PR is merged, build is triggered.
- But when I disable the **Repository Push** option in the webhook, the build is not triggering on PR merge.

2. *Setup the webhook manually*:

- In this case, the Jenkins logs show the branch name as **PR-XY** since not triggering the develop branch.
- I have set up a regex to filter branches (only develop and release are allowed) and when I add regex like **PR(.*)** then build gets triggers from the PR section (not desired case).

I want the build to be triggered from the develop branch, not as the PR branch. I have followed most of the options available in the forums but it's not working. Any help regarding this will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, it's look like most of jenkins plugins like [bitbucket plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/) does not trigger the pipeline on merge only. even though i set the bitbucket trigger options like this:
[image]
unless you add a check mark next to push option.

to solve this i used another Jenkins plugin called [Bitbucket Push and Pull Request](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request)

just make sure to uninstall Bitbucket plugin if you have it.
so you can use this one as they mentioned in there [docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket-push-and-pull-request/#plugin-content-before-you-start).
and follow the setup instructions.

**note**: i only test it with normal pipeline job

Comment: Your solution worked for me Perfectly 
All I had to do was install the plugin and on refreshing jenkins the pull requests triggered the pipeline on merge